# Is there a solution about Gson "circular reference"?

Tags: java, gson, circular-reference

I have found many articles about the circular reference with Gson, but I can't find an elegant solution.

As I know, some solutions is:

- Set the property that caused circular reference as "transient".
- exclude the property with some annotation.

But as a general question, is there some common strategy to solve the problem?

Comment: A strange game, the only way to win is to not play.  Repartition so you don't have circular references.

Comment: Is the concern just with serialization, or is it also with establishing the correct links during deserialization?

Comment: Yes there is!
Take a look at this post that includes a
[GraphAdapterBuilder example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036958/the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-bidirectional-recursive-relationships

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22271096/3315914

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no automated solution for circular references in Gson.
The only JSON-producing library I know of that handles circular references automatically is [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) (with Jettison backend).

EDIT: Jackson also supports handling of circular references with `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation; so while not automatic (you do need to mark references that need Object Id handling), it does allow solving most cases.

Comment: Correct, Gson does not have an automatic solution for circular references, nor does it offer a serialization solution other than marking Java fields to be skipped and/or writing custom serialization code.  Alternatively, Jackson provides an annotation-based solution for serialization and deserialization concerns.  See point #7 at http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/11/entry_434.html

Comment: Thanks, I hava solved the problem by excluding fields indirectly. And I will study XStream when I have free time.

Comment: Plus one for XStream. The only viable solution I've found that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

You might need `@JsonBackReference` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Since Gson doesn't properly handle circular references, and in some cases you may need to call the parent entity from its child, you can do this. Say we have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servers_postgres")
public class PostgresServer implements Serializable {

    public PostgresServer() {
        this.tables = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_server")
    private Integer serverId;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "server", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PostgresTable> tables;

    @Column(length = 250)
    private String serverAddress;

    @Column(length = 250)
    private String name;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "postgres_tables")
    public class PostgresTable implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_table")
        private Integer tableId;

        @Column(length = 250)
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_server", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_postgres_tables"))
        private PostgresServer server;
    }
```

In this case, you may need to get a PostgresServer reference from a PostgresTable entity. So, instead of excluding **PostgresServer** from serialization, **you simply set its List of tables to null**. For example:

```
//Assuming a List<PostgresTable>...
postgresTables.forEach(postgresTable -> postgresTable.getServer().setTables(null));
```

This is how i solve circular references with Gson. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

I am looking into this issue as well. Gson does not provide a default solution so far. What you can do is:

Option 1: Create an exclusion strategy which implements ExclusionStrategy to exclude the class and/or field in the circular reference;

Option 2: Use annotations to mark the field to be transient to avoid serialization;

Option 3: Create your own type adapter