# Gson serialize circular references only one way

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, circular-reference

I got the following structure:

```
abstract class Node {
    Connector output;

    @Expose
    List<Connector> inputs;

    @Expose
    String someproperty;
    @Expose
    int someother;
    int thirdOne;
    ...
}

abstract class Connector {
    @Expose
    Node owner;
    @Expose
    Connector peer;

    public void connect(Connector peer) {
      this.peer=peer;
      peer.peer=this;
    }
    ...
}
```

which should be serialized to JSON:

```
{
    ConcreteNodeClassName1: {
       someproperty:"foo",
       someother: 1,
       children: {
         {ConcreteNodeClassName2: ...
          children:{
            ...
          }
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Every node has one output connector, and several input connectors. The connectors reference the owning nodes via the `owner` field.

If I now call `gson.toJson(rootNode);` I get an stack overflow exception, because the `owner` field points back to the owning module. But the owner field needs to be exposed, in order to let gson descend to the next Node.

I've also tried writing custom serializers - with no success.

How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplication of ["Is there a solution about Gson "circular reference"?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402832/is-there-a-solution-about-gson-circular-reference?rq=1)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as this question is not about serializing circular references. Its about how to serialize only one direction of this circles. Also it uses only one field, not two separate fields to differentiate between parent and child references.

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/a/22271096/3315914

Comment: @k_wave Did you find a solution for your problem? I am stuck with the same issue :-(

Comment: My solution was to change to jackson as serializer - works fine.