# Trying to serialize an object to json using GSON -> get huge recursive error

Tags: java, serialization, gson

My code:

```
public class Faction implements Serializable {

private static Set<Faction> factions = new HashSet<>();

private transient static Set<UUID> factionOperator = new HashSet<>();

private transient static Map<UUID, Faction> onlineFPlayers = new HashMap<>();

private String announcement;

private String name;

private UUID leader;

private Map<UUID, Boolean> players = new HashMap<>();

private transient Set<UUID> factionChatPlayers = new HashSet<>();

private transient Set<UUID> invitedPlayers = new HashSet<>();

private Power power = new Power(this);

private Region region;

private double credit = 0;


public static void save() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(Krene.get().getDataFolder() + "\\factions.json");
        gson.toJson(factions, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In the class there are a few methods to do other things. But basically I want to serialize these to a json file (the serialization code is in the method save()) - but I get a huge error.

Error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:551) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:307)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:205)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968) ~[?:?]

Why am I receiving this error? Bare in mind, the classes Region and Power both implement Serializable (I think this is necessary, correct me if I am wrong?).

Is it the serialization of UUIDs? Should I serialize them as strings?

Comment: new Power(this). If Power has a reference to Faction, you have a circular dependency. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22271096/3315914

Comment: @rpax Power does have a reference to a faction, looking at that link now!

Comment: have you solved your problem? If so, post your solution ;)