# How to solve circular reference when serializing an object which have a class member with the same type of that object

Tags: json, rest, serialization, gson, circular-reference

I'm facing this issue when using Gson to serialize an object which has a class member with the same type:

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1447

The object:

```
public class StructId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String Name;
public StructType Type;
public StructId ParentId;
public StructId ChildId;
```

And since StructId contains ParentId/ChildId with the same type I was getting infinite loop when trying to serialize it, so what I did is:

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {

        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false; //(clazz == StructId.class);
        }

        /**
          * Custom field exclusion goes here
          */
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            //Ignore inner StructIds to solve circular serialization
            return ( f.getName().equals("ParentId") || f.getName().equals("ChildId") ); 
        }

     })
    /**
      * Use serializeNulls method if you want To serialize null values 
      * By default, Gson does not serialize null values
      */
    .serializeNulls()
    .create();
```

But this is not good enough cause I need the data inside Parent/Child and ignoring them while serializing is not a solution.
How is it possible to solve it?

Related to the answer marked as Solution:

I have such a struct:
- Struct1
 -- Table
    --- Variable1

The object before serialization is:
[image]

And Json that is generated is:
[image]

As you can see, the ParentId of Table is "Struct1" but the ChildId of "Struct1" is empty and it should be "Table"

B.R.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `ExclusionStrategy` is not the right approach to solve this problem.

I would rather suggest to use [`JsonSerializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) and [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)
customized for your `StructId` class.
(May be an approach using [`TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) would be even better,
but I didn't have enough Gson experience do get this working.)

So you would create your `Gson` instance by:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(StructId.class, new StructIdSerializer())
    .registerTypeAdapter(StructId.class, new StructIdDeserializer())
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .create();
```

The `StructIdSerializer` class below is responsible for converting a `StructId` to JSON.
It converts its properties `Name`, `Type` and `ChildId` to JSON.
Note that it does not convert the property `ParentId` to JSON,
because doing that would produce infinite recursion.

```
public class StructIdSerializer implements JsonSerializer<StructId> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(StructId src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("Name", src.Name);
        jsonObject.add("Type", context.serialize(src.Type));
        jsonObject.add("ChildId", context.serialize(src.ChildId));  // recursion!
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

The `StructIdDeserializer` class below is responsible for converting JSON to a `StructId`.
It converts the JSON properties `Name`, `Type` and `ChildId`
to corresponding Java fields in `StructId`.
Note that the `ParentId` Java field is reconstructed from the JSON nesting structure,
because it is not directly contained as a JSON property.

```
public class StructIdDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<StructId> {

    @Override
    public StructId deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
        StructId id = new StructId();
        id.Name = json.getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString();
        id.Type = context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("Type"), StructType.class);
        JsonElement childJson = json.getAsJsonObject().get("ChildId");
        if (childJson != null) {
            id.ChildId = context.deserialize(childJson, StructId.class);  // recursion!
            id.ChildId.ParentId = id;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

I tested the code above with this JSON input example

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Type": "A",
    "ChildId": {
        "Name": "Jane",
        "Type": "B",
        "ChildId": {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Type": "A"
        }
    }
}
```

by deserializing it with
`StructId root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("example.json"), StructId.class);`,
then by serializing that with
`System.out.println(gson.toJson(root));`
and got the original JSON again.

Comment: Sounds good. I implemented the Serializer/Deserializer solution and I have few questions: 1) why did you use addProperty for Name and not add as value? 2) the json arriving to server controller is like this: {"++\"Name\"":"+\"struct\""} and when calling the id.Name = json.getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString(); getting null

Comment: @zbeedatm 1) I used `addProperty("Name", ...)` because that is enough to add a JSON primitive.  
2) This JSON looks weird. It would be better to add a formatted JSON example to your question
instead of squeezing it into a comment. I have also added my JSON input example to the answer.

Comment: These charecters apears because of: URLEncoder.encode(jsonDesttinationIdString, ENCODING). But it was working as expected before using the customized serializer... will find a away to handle it in other side by Encoder.decode maybe

Comment: Ok basically seems to be working. But without the ParentId and this data is needed too... so what do you suggest? to try the other way of TypeAdapter? maybe it's achievable there

Comment: @zbeedatm For me the `ParentId` was correctly set in the Java objects, and in JSON it is not neeeded. I suggest you stick to the serializer/deserializer approach and get it working. With the TypeAdapter approach you would get the same functionality, just only with better performance in case of huge JSON contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot @thomas-fritsch , I used the Adapter approch at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show one way to make serialization (so I do not handle de-serialization) with `TypeAdapter` and `ExclusionStrategy`. This might not be the most beautiful implementation but it is quite generic anyway.

This solution makes use of the fact that your struct is some kind of a bi-directional linked list and given any node in that list we just need to separate the serialization of parents and children so that those are serialized just in one direction to avoid circular references.

First we need configurable `ExclusionStrategy` like:

```
public class FieldExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    private final List<String> skipFields;

    public FieldExclusionStrategy(String... fieldNames) {
        skipFields = Arrays.asList(fieldNames);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return skipFields.contains(f.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then the `TypeAdapter` would be like:

```
public class LinkedListAdapter extends TypeAdapter<StructId> {

private static final String PARENT_ID = "ParentId";
private static final String CHILD_ID = "ChildId";
private Gson gson;

@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, StructId value) throws IOException {
    // First serialize everything but StructIds
    // You could also use type based exclusion strategy
    // but for brevity I use just this one  
    gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(
                    new FieldExclusionStrategy(CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID))
            .create();
    JsonObject structObject = gson.toJsonTree(value).getAsJsonObject(); 
    JsonObject structParentObject;
    JsonObject structChildObject;

    // If exists go through the ParentId side in one direction.
    if(null!=value.ParentId) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new FieldExclusionStrategy(CHILD_ID))
                .create();
        structObject.add(PARENT_ID, gson.toJsonTree(value.ParentId));

        if(null!=value.ParentId.ChildId) {
            gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new FieldExclusionStrategy(PARENT_ID))
                    .create();
            structParentObject = structObject.get(PARENT_ID).getAsJsonObject();
            structParentObject.add(CHILD_ID, gson.toJsonTree(value.ParentId.ChildId).getAsJsonObject());
        }
    }
    // And also if exists go through the ChildId side in one direction.
    if(null!=value.ChildId) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new FieldExclusionStrategy(PARENT_ID))
                .create();
        structObject.add(CHILD_ID, gson.toJsonTree(value.ChildId));

        if(null!=value.ChildId.ParentId) {
            gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new FieldExclusionStrategy(CHILD_ID))
                    .create();

            structChildObject = structObject.get(CHILD_ID).getAsJsonObject();
            structChildObject.add(PARENT_ID, gson.toJsonTree(value.ChildId.ParentId).getAsJsonObject());
        }
    }

    // Finally write the combined result out. No need to initialize gson anymore
    // since just writing JsonElement
    gson.toJson(structObject, out);
}

@Override
public StructId read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    return null;
}}
```

Testing it:

```
@Slf4j
public class TestIt extends BaseGsonTest {

@Test
public void test1() {
    StructId grandParent   = new StructId();

    StructId parent   = new StructId();
    grandParent.ChildId = parent;
    parent.ParentId = grandParent;

    StructId child = new StructId();
    parent.ChildId = child;
    child.ParentId = parent;

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .registerTypeAdapter(StructId.class, new LinkedListAdapter())
            .create();

    log.info("\n{}", gson.toJson(parent));
}}
```

Would give you something like:

```
{
  "Name": "name1237598030",
  "Type": {
       "name": "name688766789"
   },
  "ParentId": {
  "Name": "name1169146729",
  "Type": {
     "name": "name2040352617"
  }
 },
"ChildId": {
  "Name": "name302155142",
  "Type": {
     "name": "name24606376"
   }
 }
}
```

Names in my test material are just by default initialized with `"name"+hashCode()`

Comment: Hi again, I realized that 2 levels is not good enough... I need to fill the whole structure tree till last node

Comment: Did you try it? Think it should work. The only thing is that the root node is always the node you give and it will then have parent & child tree

Comment: I edited my post with more information related to your solution, pls take a look.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict it to 2-3 levels only and prevent the infinite loop? I think it will be enough if each object can hold it's complete filled Parent & Child objects

Comment: If I understood your edits correct you want to replicate StructId=59 again inside its ParentId, StructId=68  (but without its ParentId, structId=68 again, to prevent rtecursion) . But why? You have the data already as the root element. Maybe you should rethink what is your actual problem and perhaps reformulate your question or ask another question?

Comment: Yes I need this data (59 as child of 68). I have a Junit test that is passing with normal flow and when running the same test through the rest api and dealing with serializing objects it fails. I edited my post again and gave the logic where it fails if it helps to understand. It fails when it's entering the third if and calling the method itself again -recursion- with structureIterator which has no children.

Comment: I edited your LinkedListAdapter to add more nested level, and I mad a progress. Will mark it as solution since I don't have any other way to deal with it meanwhile, hopefully will not face new issues as I go on on with my tests.

Comment: @zbeedatm As you wish but I still think that there might have been even better solution if the real problem was better known. I see your test case but not sure why you need to do it that way. Maybe I'll investigate it  more later.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misleading you guys, based on this post :

[Is there a solution about Gson "circular reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402832/is-there-a-solution-about-gson-circular-reference)

"there is no automated solution for circular references in Gson. The only JSON-producing library I know of that handles circular references automatically is [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) (with Jettison backend)."

But that is case you don't use Jackson! If you are using Jackson already for building your REST API controllers so why not to use it for making the serialization. No need for external compopnents like: Gson or XStream.

The solution with Jackson:

Serialization:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
        jsonDesttinationIdString = ow.writeValueAsString(destinationId);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new SpecificationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

De-serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        destinationStructId = destinationId.isEmpty() ? null : mapper.readValue(URLDecoder.decode(destinationId, ENCODING), StructId.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SpecificationException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

And most important, you must use the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation:

```
//@JsonIdentityInfo(
//        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
//        property = "Name")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, 
      property = "id")
public class StructId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("id") // I added this field to have a unique identfier
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept binary format instead of json, you can try https://github.com/alipay/fury out. Json is a text format, which can't express circular reference, you must cropoff circular field by @JsonIgnore annotation. But the deserialized object from json will lose circular reference, the ignored data will be null.

Use fury for circular reference serialization example:

```
Fury fury = Fury.builder().withRefTracking(true).build();
byte[] data = fury.serializeJavaObject(structId);
StructId newStructId = fury.deserializeJavaObject(data, StructId.class);
```

Similar frameworks such as kryo/fst can be used for this too.