# Why do I need to use transient keyword to avoid java.lang.StackOverflowError using Gson and a SocketChannel attribute?

Tags: java, json, database, gson, transient

I'm using Gson to mantain a DB of users. Why did I need to use transient for socketCh attribute to avoid StackOverflowError?

```
public class User {
    String username;
    String password;
    ArrayList<String> friends;
    transient SocketChannel socketCh = null;
    ...
}
```

When "fileWriter.write(gson.toJson(usersDB))" was executed and socketCh was not transient there was the stackOverflow problem

```
static void updateOrCreateDBFile() {
    File file = new File(nameJsonDBFile);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            usersDB = new HashMap<String, User>();
            System.out.println(name3d + ": Creating the database json file");
        }
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        System.out.println(name3d+": usersDB "+usersDB);
        fileWriter.write(gson.toJson(usersDB));
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems `SocketChannel` has a circular references, which is not supported by Gson
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402832/is-there-a-solution-about-gson-circular-reference
https://github.com/google/gson/issues/137

I hope there's possible to move `SocketChannel` outside of the User entity.

Comment: You can't serialize a `SocketChannel` anyway, but yes it definitely shouldn't be inside `User`, that's bad design.

Comment: I use socketCh for some reasons: 1) doing logout in different context I can pass simply a User user as parameter and I can set user as offline (socketChannel == null) and remove it from an HashMap<SocketChannel, User> socketToUserDB popolated by online user and used to obtain user from the client channel opened with ServerChannel.accept(). 2) because I'm not sure I can always get connection channel from the context (I can actualy but I'm feeling safer leaving it at the moment)